# Отступы между блоками на flex

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть следующий макет: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверстано так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block3_header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 87px;
}

.block3_header span {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #070707;
}

.block3_subText {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.block3_subText span {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium';
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #070707;
}

.container_skills {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.block3_skills {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.block3_skill {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.block3_stars {
  display: flex;
}

.block3_stars img {
  margin-right: 9px;
}

.block3_stars:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.block3_subTitle {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.block3_subTitle span {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #828282;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container_skills">
  <div class="block3_skills">
    <div class="block3_skill">
      <div class="block3_logo">
        <img src="/img/PS.svg" alt="Photoshop">
      </div>
      <div class="block3_subTitle">
        <span>
                                Adobe<br>Photoshop
                            </span>
      </div>
      <div class="block3_stars">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/StarWithoutFill.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3_skill">
      <div class="block3_logo">
        <img src="/img/AI.svg" alt="Adobe Illustrator">
      </div>
      <div class="block3_subTitle">
        <span>
                                Adobe<br>Illustrator
                            </span>
      </div>
      <div class="block3_stars">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/StarWithoutFill.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/StarWithoutFill.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3_skill">
      <div class="block3_logo">
        <img src="/img/AE.svg" alt="Adobe After Effects">
      </div>
      <div class="block3_subTitle">
        <span>
                                Adobe<br>After Effects
                            </span>
      </div>
      <div class="block3_stars">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/StarWithoutFill.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block3_skill">
      <div class="block3_logo">
        <img src="/img/Figma.svg" alt="Figma">
      </div>
      <div class="block3_subTitle">
        <span>
                                Figma<br><br>
                            </span>
      </div>
      <div class="block3_stars">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/Star.svg" alt="">
        <img src="/img/StarWithoutFill.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема заключается в то, что по макету карточки с программами находятся ближе друг к другу, чем по факту у меня получились. Есть вариант во флексах как-то уменьшить отступ между блоками?

Comment: Вы можете блоку-обёртке `.block3_skills` задать `justify-content: center;` (вместо `space-evenly` как у Вас сейчас). А расстояние между внутренними блоками уже регулировать с помощью `margin`

Comment: Спасибо большое). Сработало

Comment: @humster_spb Не обязательно использовать `margin` для корректировки отступов, `gap` справится лучше, отступы будут только между `flex` элементами, у крайних элементов внешних отступов не будет.

Comment: @Pilaton, или так ) Но в данном примере не принципиально

Comment: @Pilaton, как альтернитива для gap - [tag_name]:not(:last-child) {}

Answer (score 2):

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center; // Контент по центру
flex-wrap: nowrap;
align-items: center;
grid-gap:20px; // отступы между flex элементами
```